# Table Valued Param UdtTypeName

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

.NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2010.

In MSSQL 2008, I have a simple table Type, a stored proc that takes the TVP as a parameter. It works fine in management studio.

I created a new Linq-to-SQL designer, drug my tables and procs onto the design surface, everything worked fine.

I then tried to drag the stored procedure with the table-valued-parameter on the design surface, and got this red-X error:

```
UdtTypeName property must be set for UDT parameters.
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Looks like you fell off the border of the drag-and-drop world :)

Comment: Can you please post your stored proc code here?

Answer (score 4):

LINQ to SQL doesn't support User-Defined Table Types.  See [LINQ to SQL with stored procedures and user defined table type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019414/linq-to-sql-with-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-table-type-parameter).

> Unfortunately, according to Damien [Guard], this feature isn't supported in
>   .NET 3.5, and will not be supported in .NET 4.0 either :-(