# Linq to Sql: Generic Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am using Linq-to-Sql for a C# application and am currently working on some stored procedures.  The application is for a newspaper, and a sample stored procedure is the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Articles_GetArticlesByPublication
   @publicationDate date
AS
   SELECT 
      *
   FROM 
      Articles
   WHERE
      Articles.PublicationDate=@publicationDate
```

Anyway, this query gets all of the articles where the publication date is equal to the argument (publicationDate).  How can I alter this so that the argument can handle multiple publication dates?

Also, I'd prefer not to use "BETWEEN," rather, I want to pick and choose dates.

Comment: would a from and through criteria work (contiguous dates) or do you need a list of unrelated dates?  Also, do you have times stored in your datetime PublicationDate field or just a date, like 2011-01-03 00:00?

Comment: They are just dates, so I suppose I could change it to "@publicationDate date."
I just edited my post to answer your first question.  Ideally I'd like to have it with unrelated dates.

Comment: What version of SQL are you working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native support to pass arrays/lists to the TSQL SP. However you can use XML or varchar data types. I'd prefer XML because you can easily create a table variable and select all values from passed XML into it and then use IN statement in WHERE clause (this is just a concept SQL):

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE foo AS
    @dates XML
BEGIN
...
DECLARE @datesTable TABLE ( [d] date )

INSERT INTO @datesTable
SELECT d FROM OPENXML (@dates, '/ROOT/date',1) WITH (d date)

...
SELECT... WHERE date IN (SELECT d FROM @datesTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 you can use [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) to pass multiple values to a stored procedure with XML or Comma delimited lists, but its not supported with LINQ to SQL so you'd have to use ADO.NET directly with .NET 3.5 and up.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019414/linq-to-sql-with-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-table-type-parameter/1019646#1019646) from marc_s on why it's unavailable in Linq to SQL.