# How to insert list from C sharp into SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, list, insert

I have created a list in c#, now I need to insert the list into SQL Server 2008.
Is this possible? please explain with a simple example.

Comment: You should look into [table valued parameters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters).

Comment: Smith, how the attributes in list can be assigned as parameter?

Comment: The following link helps you to provide a solution for your problem. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757818/c-sharp-insert-into-sql-table-with-list-as-parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757818/c-sharp-insert-into-sql-table-with-list-as-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C" };
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TABLE(Column)VALUES(@Column)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Column", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        foreach (var value in list)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@Column"].Value = value;
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

This just loops through all items in the list and executes one insert-command after the other with [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

**Edit**: If you want to know the most efficient ways to insert arrays(or lists) into sql-server, you should definitely read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

If you have a specific question later, you can come back and show what you've tried.

Comment: Well, that's not really an efficient way to insert a list, that's just a way to loop through a list and insert one at a time. A TVP would be a much more attractive option. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I wanted to show a simple example since i've assumed that OP just wants to insert his 1-dimensional list(one field). There was no requirement for the most efficient way ;) If he wants to know how to handle lists(arrays) most efficiently he should read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: My database has 30 columns, but what I have in list is only 20 columns and it grows dynamically based upon user.  Now, How to do the insert?

Comment: @user1671639 you need to start with a tutorial (a search can yield these pretty easily), then come back here with problems when you've written some code and can't quite get it to work. This isn't a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: I missed to pick this answer sorry for being too late :( Thank you :)

Comment: Note that in order for this to work you might have to move the definition of cmd inside the foreach loop as otherwise c# might complain that the value of @column has already been set.

Comment: @Thijser: that's not quite correct, since i'm only setting the `Value` property and not adding the parameter multiple times C# won't complain. It is perfectly valid to overwrite a `Value` of a parameter in a loop. This was tested and i have tested it again to verify that it works as expected.

Comment: Ah yes I see now I was using addwithvalue that won't work.