# How to insert a list of values into SQL Server 2008 from asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to store multiple rows at once in SQL Server. I have taken one list datatype which is storing multiple row content. Now I want to pass this list directly to SQL Server. I don't want to use for loop to insert value one by one. How can I pass the whole list as a parameter to my stored procedure?

Comment: Double: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209686/passing-list-to-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426300/how-to-insert-list-from-c-sharp-into-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma-separated string, and parse it on sql side. That is the fastest solution, so you will not have an open connection wile doing the loop on c# side.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the concept of `Batch Update` or `SQLBulkCopy` or you can pass Array as Parameter to `Command Object`.

You can also Pass the data in `XML` format to `SQL Server Stored Procedure` .

Or Simplest way create multiple appended strings for inserts as below:

```
 string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Person VALUES ( '" + txtPersonId1.Text.Trim() + "',' " +  txtPersonName1.Text + "'); "; 
    sqlText += "INSERT INTO Person VALUES ( '" + txtPersonId2.Text.Trim() + "',' " +  txtPersonName2.Text + "'); "; 
    sqlText += "INSERT INTO Person VALUES ( '" + txtPersonId3.Text.Trim() + "',' " +  txtPersonName3.Text + "'); "; 
    sqlText += "INSERT INTO Person VALUES ( '" + txtPersonId4.Text.Trim() + "',' " +  txtPersonName4.Text + "'); ";
```

All These Methods are explained over [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25457/Multiple-Ways-to-do-Multiple-Inserts).