# Insert data within multiple tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have 3 different tables in my database as below;

```
Table 1:
ResourceID |  ResourceTitle|  ResourceCategory

Table 2:
DocumentID|  DocName  |  DocSize

Table 3:
ResourceID  |  DocumentID
```

Now I want to add some values into the above tables (using a C# .ASP.NET) respectively.

- The first table I have **one row** to be added into the Resource
  table(Table 1).
- The second table I have **multiple rows** to be added into the
  document table(Table 2).
- The third table needs to keep **all the ids** from the first two tables as a foreign key in ResourceDocument Table(Table 3).

All of the processes need to be done in one single transaction, so there would be a loop for the second table data in my asp.net c# class.

the problem that I have is finding the right way to handle the transaction to do this job, also I need to make sure while these processes are running it doesn't let the other users to modify these data.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is the problem with right way to handle transaction? If you're using some kind of ORM, there's a big possibility that it uses unit of work pattern and all your database actions will be wrapped to transaction on commit, if not, you can use `TransactionScope` to handle transaction scope manually.

Comment: If you using Linq, you can do all your changes and at the end of ever Loop cast the SubmitChanges() method. I'm not sure where the Problem is?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655883(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table valued parameters in stored procedures.

This is a good [LINK](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/) how to create & use **TVP** in stored procedures.

Then you need to pass **TVP** from your page/form.

You can have a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code) to get an idea for that.

Example for creating table type :

```
CREATE TYPE yourDocumentTableType AS TABLE 
(
    docID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    docName VARCHAR(50),
    docSize INT 
)
GO
```

Your stored procedure should be like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourInsertOperation 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Param1 INT, 
    @Param2 VARCHAR(20),
    --......your parameter list goes here
    -- here you would pass the records for your document table
    @YourTableValuedParam dbo.yourDocumentTableType READONLY 
AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- declare temp table type & assign the TVP to it
        DECLARE @TempDocuments dbo.yourDocumentTableType

        INSERT INTO @TempDocuments (docName, docSize)
        SELECT docName, docSize FROM @YourTableValuedParam

        DECLARE @ResourceID BIGINT            

        --Marking the start of a transaction
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        --Inserting records into resource table
        INSERT INTO resourceTable(column1, column2) VALUES (@param1, @param2)

        --selecting resourceID to be inserted into document table & resource-document table
        SELECT @ResourceID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TempDocuments)
            BEGIN                        
                DECLARE @DocumentID BIGINT

                --Inserting records into document table from the table valued parameter
                INSERT INTO documentTable(docName, docSize, resourceID)
                SELECT TOP 1 docName, docSize, @ResourceID FROM @TempDocuments

                SELECT @DocumentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                INSERT INTO resouceDocumentTable(resourceID, docID) VALUES (@ResourceID, @DocumentID)

                DELETE TOP (1) FROM @TempDocuments
            END

    --Checking for any error in the whole transaction (all 3 table insert operation)
    IF @@ERROR > 0
        --rollback if there was any error
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    ELSE
        --commit whole transaction (all 3 table insert operation)
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
GO
```

Comment: The above strategy is good but the code is not working properly, the following line has error (Must declare the scalar variable)
        'SET TempDocuments = YourTableValuedParam '

Comment: @AliShahrokhi, check now the code is working. Instead of SET statement, it needed to use insert statement, as the variable is of type table. I have tested this & it is working. Sorry for delayed response.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DECLARE @ResourceID int
 DECLARE @DocumentID int
 Insert into Table 1(ResourceTitle,  ResourceCategory)value("values","values")          

 SELECT @ResourceID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 Insert into Table 2( DocName , DocSize) value("values","values")
 SELECT @DocumentID =SCOPE_IDENTITY()
 Insert into Table 3( ResourceID  ,  DocumentID) values(@ResourceID ,@DocumentID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have written the same query but as I said I need to add multiple rows in the second Table at the same time,  So when a user click on a button then a resource including multiple documents save in a database at the same time. The way that you wrote this is for one resource and one document only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transaction scope as you can see this link

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2010/05/using-transactions-with-linq-to-sql.html