# Passing CheckBoxList parameters to Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, checkboxlist

I have an asp.net checkboxlist which keeps my numbers

```
01
02
03
04
05
.
.
.
```

And I have a number field in my sql server database table, which can contain the values above. So when above fields checked in my checkboxlist, I want my stored procedure to filter the table with the checked values.

what is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way by which you can pass the DataTable to store procedure.
Here is a link for the same
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412802/Sending-a-DataTable-to-a-Stored-Procedure
[How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

Comment: Not possible to pass DataTable in sql server 2005 I think

Comment: then you have to loop through you list one by one and then insert or update.