# Bulk insert with single hit of Databse using Asp.net or Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, silverlight-4.0

Iam using vs2010 How to insert a list of 500 records in a single hit of Databse in asp.net or Silverlight.I faced this question in one of  my interview.I tried in Vs2010 with ADO connection. can you please suggest answers

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 allows Table-valued parameters to a stored procedure. See [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code) for how to use them in .NET land.

Comment: i know about using stored procedure to insert a table.but i asked about bulk insert in a table with single hit from asp page to DB