# How to populate a table valued parameter using a custom DbDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient, table-valued-parameters, dbdatareader

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4), `System.Data.SqlClient` supports populating table-valued parameters from `DataTable`, `DbDataReader` or `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` objects.

I wrote the following code which populate a table valued paremeter using `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` objects :

```
static void Main()
{       
    List<int> idsToSend = ...
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();    
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ...
                                              FROM ... 
                                              INNER JOIN @ids mytable ON ...", connection);

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ids", SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            TypeName = "int_list_type",
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = GetSqlDataRecords(idsToSend) //returns IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> 
        });

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //consume reader...
    }
}
```

It works perfectly.

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) page says:

> You can also use any object derived from `DbDataReader` to stream rows
>   of data to a table-valued parameter.

I would like  to use a custom `DbDataReader` instead to pass the row data. Something like this:

```
public class CustomDataReader : DbDataReader
{
    public CustomDataReader(IEnumerable<int> values)
    {           
    }

    //implementation of other abstract methods and fields required by DbDataReader
    //...
}
```

I have changed the following line in the initial code example :

```
Value = GetSqlDataRecords(idsToSend)
=>
Value = new CustomDataReader(idsToSend)
```

If I run the code, it give me the following exception during execution of `command.ExecuteReader()` :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in System.Data.dll Additional information: Specified method is not
>   supported.

I have put a breakpoint on ALL methods and properties of my `CustomDbDataReader` class : none of them are called before I got the exception so its probably not related to the implementation of the `DbDataReader`

---

EDIT : here is the stack trace, as requested :

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(SqlCommand cmd, _SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ConsoleApplication211.Program.Main() in Program.cs:line 51
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the stack trace of the exception

Comment: @stuartd : done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42099675/2996339

Comment: The only difference I can see is that it use a stored procedure, is this a requirement to use a `DbDataReader` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement [`GetSchemaTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getschematable(v=vs.110).aspx), which is not marked abstract.

See also: [How To Retrieve Column Schema by Using the DataReader GetSchemaTable Method and Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310107/how-to-retrieve-column-schema-by-using-the-datareader-getschematable-method-and-visual-c-.net)