# User defined Table-Valued parameters columns order without attributes applied to properties, is it possible?

Tags: c#, t-sql, reflection, table-valued-parameters

As far [as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221640/921054) SQL expects the columns of passed DataReader to have the same order as the columns of user defined type.

At the same time [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

So it implies that the only attributeless safe order of properties is alphabetical, isn't it? That is when I create some utility method to wrap a collection of entities with DataReader which is later passed as parameter to SP call.

Is my understanding correct or may be some magic exists which allows to avoid ordering problems?

Comment: No; read the quote you linked to. The parameters must be named, and be referred to by name and not by position index or sequencing.

Comment: First, what do you mean by "parameters must be names"?
Second, it is SQL Server (or whatever) that accesses DataReader. Debug shows that columns are accessed by external code via index, not via name.