# How to read in a Dictionary<string,List<CustomClass>> to SQL Server 2008 and display the dictionary in a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to pass a Dictionary> into SQL. I think that table-valued parameters are the best way to go but I'm not entirely sure how to implement them in this case.  I obtain values for my dictionary in my script in visual studio, but I will not know what the values will be or how many, until they're displayed in a table.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a table-valued parameter and pass your list as a `Structured` parameter.

Comment: "Lists" (or "arrays") in SQL Server should always be represented by **rows in a table** - don't use comma-separated hacks or anything like that - those all violate even the **first normal form** of database design!

Comment: @Tab those might be great ideas for < 2008, but not for 2008+

Comment: Seems like alot of overhead scraping data from a database only to write it back into the database... why not write a procedure/view to give you the needed data instead of the scraping? (Possibly using temp tables)

Comment: My question was actually inaccurate now that I'm looking at my script.  I actually need to pass a Dictionary<string,List<CustomClass>> into SQL.  I think that table-valued parameters are the best way to go but I'm not entirely sure how to implement them in this case.

Comment: What's unusual about this case that the normal ways of implementing them won't work?

Answer (score 0):

The following post should lead you in the right direction.  You have to create a User Defined Table type, a stored procedure that uses it as a parameter and then create a Data Table in C# that is used as the parameter in ADO.NET.

[How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)