# SQL, trying to get rid of large IN cluase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-in

I have a table,

`Contacts:
Contact_ID (int)
ContactName (nvarchar)`

I am given a list of contact IDs to select from. Usually, i would just do

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE IN (List of contact ID)
```

The problem is, the list of contact IDs could potentially get very big, like 50k or more.

So my question is, Is there a way to deal with a large list of contact IDs without having to use the IN clause?

EDIT: I'm using Microsoft sql server. The query and the contact IDs are built during runtime and passed on to sqlCommand class (c#) to be executed.

Comment: use a join between two tables and allow the INNER join to eliminate records... use a correlated subquery and the 'exists' clause (or similar depending on RDBMS)  (Exists is ***generally*** fastest followed by inner join, followed by IN)  so what RDBMS? and is the List of contact ID's in a table somewhere?  (not sure what you mean by "Given a list of contacts"  Insert the "List" into a temp table and use exists, or inner join... but that has overhead... what are you trying to achieve?  Just improved readability?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Every optimizer behaves differently

Comment: Not sure which DBMS you're on, but most will let you put those IDs in a temp table and join to the temp table. That will probably be faster.

Comment: SQLServer automatically converts large IN clauses (>50 items or so) to TempTable + EXISTS. There is no performance benefit in changing.

Comment: @xQbert seems like my question is kinda vague, sorry. I should clarify that the query is built during runtime, and so is the list of contact IDs. When i tried to run this query with a large in clause, it sql server gives me a "run out of internal resource" error.

Comment: @adrianm . . . Do you have a reference for that behavior?

Comment: Can you query for the contact IDs? If so, you could use "Select * from contacts where contactid in (select contactid from contactIDs) tbl1" .... or something similar

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Discussed in the comments here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/when-is-a-seek-not-a-seek.aspx.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, only looking at performance and query plan for different number of items in my own tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a table type with a single column and a clustered primary key.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ContactId AS TABLE
(
    ContactId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

Pass the values into the query using a table valued parameter.

Change your query to

```
SELECT *
FROM Contacts
WHERE contactID  IN (SELECT y.contactID FROM @yourtablevaluedparameter y)
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is there to get the number of rows taken into account as the optimal plan for 50K may well be different than for 1.

[You can find some example C# code for populating a TVP here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779567/73226)

Comment: creating another table might be the way to go. I'm trying out this solution right now. Will let you know! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want performance, I would use the EXISTS clause.

```
SELECT c.Contact_ID, c.ContactName
FROM Contacts c
WHERE EXISTS (List of contact ID)
```

Comment: Not clear how the OP is supposed to use this with a "List of contact ID". `IN` and `EXISTS` give the same plan in SQL Server anyway (unlike `NOT IN` vs `NOT EXISTS`)

Comment: Sorry, but when I answered he did not give much information about his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table and populate your contact id in the form of rows.
Do an inner join between your table and temp table like the below.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contacts c
join #temptable t
on c.id=t.id
```

If you introduce index on the Join column  in your temp table then your query will be more faster.