# How to insert List<T> into database

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I save a List in a database at once without iterating through the whole list and saving each object seperately to the database.

```
//So not like this solution
foreach(T t in data){
    //Call function to save with stored procedure
    Database.Save(t);
}
```

***(Also without using the entity framework)*** (I only seem to get solutions based on the entity framework or Dapper.Net on StackOverflow.)

Is this even possible by sending the list in some way to the database and using a stored procedure?

---

@Edit Additional information

I'm currently running on SQL 2012 and want to be able to reroll everything if something did not work!

Comment: Does t map to an entity in the database? Because you can use datatables

Comment: At it's simplest, you could manually create a bunch of INSERT statements and execute them as a single batch against the database - there are a million ways to skin this cat!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using at least SQL Server 2008, then you can use a [Table Valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) to do this. This [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code) covers the topic.

Essentially you create a Type in SQL, and then something in C# to convert you data to a `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` which matches the type as given.

Comment: OP needs to mention SQL Server version because this is not possible prior to 2008.

Comment: @nikhilvartak that's true. I'll add that information in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Table Valued Parameter` to pass collection to stored procedure.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)