# Send parameters for IN operator in sql using parameterized queries in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, parameter-passing, parameterized-query

I am using asp.net , C# to make my app.

In there for database oprations I am suing parametrised queries.

Here is a code

```
mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand();
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ids", ids);

switch (privilegeType.ToString())
{
    case "CorporateLead":
        myQuery = @"SELECT 
  leavea.applied_leave_id_pk,
  leavea.emp_id_fk,
  leavea.emp_name AS NAME,
  leavea.start_date,
  leavea.end_date,
  leavea.is_half_day,
 ..............
FROM
  lea_applied_leave AS leavea 
  INNER JOIN emp_employee_master AS emp 
    ON emp.employee_master_id_pk = leavea.emp_id_fk 
WHERE emp.`corporate_id_fk` IN (@ids) ;
```

In there ids will include (10,11,12)

Ids is a string. Parameter counter will be vary according to the login user. I pass that string as a parameterized query.

But when app execute this it only getting the result which belongs to id of 10.

When I execute this code directly on MySQL it shows correct result.

So what is the wrong here? Is there any way to send parameters for IN operator?

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(emp.corporate_id_fk, @ids);` But keep in mind it could be slow (no index usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are not a substitution for string operations. It takes the value 'as-is'.

That said, your SQL should read like this:

```
WHERE emp.`corporate_id_fk` IN (@id1, @id2, @id3) ;
```

Add a separate parameter for each value in your SQL statement.

Comment: parameter counter will be vary according to the login user.

Comment: So you have to dynamically create SQL. That isn't that hard, is it?

Comment: What about the programming part?   mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id1", id1);

Comment: Yes, you have to split that too.

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an exception? What is the code used?

Answer (score 0):

From my past experience (which is not extensive), Passing an array of data in SqlCommand.Parameters doesn't really work as expected.

Though there are a few ways in which we can do this.

**1) Table Value Parameters**

Have a look at the following answer and links in it.

[How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

**2) Create query using string builder (or string format)**

Get @IDs in a format that we can directly put it in using string format.

```
string Ids = @"'10', '11', '12'";

string myQuery = string.format(@"SELECT leavea.applied_leave_id_pk, leavea.emp_id_fk,   leavea.emp_name AS NAME, leavea.start_date, leavea.end_date, leavea.is_half_day FROM lea_applied_leave AS leavea INNER JOIN emp_employee_master AS emp ON emp.employee_master_id_pk = leavea.emp_id_fk WHERE emp.`corporate_id_fk` IN {0}", Ids);
```

This approach allows to keep the query and inputs separated.

**3) Passing inputs as an XML**

Create an XElement from the Ids. Using same approach pass XElement instead. And then have a look at the below link for examples of how to use the XML in SQL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187897.aspx