# Best way to update the value of a "list" of variables in a SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a doubt regarding the update of the value of several bool variables into a table. My structure is:

In C#, I have several bool variables like

```
public bool varName1 = false;
public bool varName2 = false;
public bool varName3 = false;
```

etc. (More than a hundred)

In SQL Server 2014, I have a table called "DigitalInputs" and there I have the data as follows:

Name (nvarchar 255) | Value (bit)

VarName1 | True

VarName2 | False

VarName3 | True

etc.

My question is, if I want to update Values in the table of sql server with values of bool variables in C#, which would be the most efficient way to do it?

Now what I was using was:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DigitalInputs SET Value = @VALUE WHERE Name = @NAME", connection))
{

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("NAME", "varName1"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("VALUE", varName1.ToString()));
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Execute the non query
command.Parameters.Clear(); //Clear the parameters to add later new ones

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("NAME", "varName2"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("VALUE", varName2.ToString()));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Parameters.Clear();
```

etc.

It worked fine at the beginning but now with more than 100 bool variables, it executes really slowly (3 times per second). I was thinking about using maybe a data-table or an iEnumerable list but I'm not sure how I should do it, I'm really new in C# and SQL.

**//EDITED, questions regarding TVP**

I'm having some problems in implementing DataTable solution, what I have right now is:

In SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.DigitalInputs AS TABLE
(
Name NVARCHAR(255),
Value BIT
)

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateValue
(@tableData AS dbo.DigitalInputs READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE dbo.DigitalInputs
    SET dbo.DigitalInputs.Value = @tableData.Value
    FROM dbo.DigitalInputs
    INNER JOIN @tableData ON dbo.DigitalInputs.Name = @tableData.Name
END
```

I'm not sure about SQL syntax in this procedure creation, I'm a bit lost with SQL language.

And in C#:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable ();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(bool));
dataTable.Rows.Add("varName1", varName1);
//etc...

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UpdateValue", connection))
{
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@tableData", dataTable);
parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
}
```

It seems like SqlDbType.Structured doesn't exist and I don't know why, I have the following error: *error CS0117: `System.Data.SqlDbType' does not contain a definition for`Structured'.*
I'm writing the code in Unity3D, using Monodevelop 5.9.6 .

Answer (score 3):

You can try one of these.

1) Table Value Parameters

Have a look at the following answer and links in it.

[How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

2) Passing inputs as an XML

Create an XElement from the Ids. Using same approach pass XElement instead. And then have a look at the below link for examples of how to use the XML in SQL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187897.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna try table value parameters!

Comment: I've been working around the solution with TVP but I cannot get it right. I edited my question to add my new inquiries. If you can have a look at them I'll be very grateful, thanks!

Comment: Apologies for delay. Am sure you would have solved it by now, if not, can you check the .net version you use? Not sure but I don't think it was present in version before .net 4.0, from below msdn documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.90).aspx