# how to pass multiple records in a function of sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i just tried to pass table type as a parameter in function of sql server

**Scenario** :
       i Have **customer** and **sales** tables.. When i put an entry in sales form that has to affect both tables. So i decided to create a function to pass both table values as a type and execute the process in it.But i couldn't.
 In this case **Customer has one record and Sales has one or more records**. Now i need to know how to declare function and how to execute it in C#.net.

**customer**

```
cus_id                                
cus_name                              
cus_totpurchasecost
```

**Sales**

```
cus_id              
sales_id         
item_id                  
item_qty               
item_cost
```

customer(1,'ddddd',10000)

```
sales(1,1,2,2000)          
sales(1,2,6,1000)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us the function you tried to execute? Did you receive an error?

Comment: You don't have to define a DB function, you can do this all from the C# code, that way you are in control of creating and inserting the records into your database. Creating a function and passing it a type seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

You could create a Stored Procedure to add your records to applicable tables (not a function) and then use ADO.NET to execute it. This is the "old school" approach and there are many examples online.

Commonly, you would create a stored procedure for each of the CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) and then have methods in your C# code that call these Store Procs parsing the required params.

This is "safer" than constructing the SQL code in your C# code as it avoids the risk of SQL injection attacks (although not entirely).

See:

1. [How to create a Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms345415.aspx)
2. [ADO.NET Basics](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/18fc30/understanding-the-basics-of-ado-net/)

The other way would be to use an ORM (Object Relation Mapper) or MicroORM framework to make this work a bit easier. This is considered the "newer" way to do things.

See:

1. [Entity Framework (ORM)](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)
2. [PetaPoco (MicroORM)](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)

Answer (score -1):

you can use cursor in side that function for row by  row operation.