# Insert multiple rows with parameters Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to perform a multiple values insert in Sql Server while using parameters, to be precise, having a command like this:

```
com = new SqlCommand("insert into myTable values (@recID,@tagID)", con);
com.Parameters.Add("@recID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = recID;
com.Parameters.Add("@tagID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tagID;
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is there a way to perform a multiple values single insert with parameters taking into account that parameters may be different for each value? (Example: tagID may be always different)

I have been searching in Internet but no luck so far, thanks in advance, greetings.

Comment: TVP-parameter, temp table.

Comment: You can use a table valued parameters : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a table valued parameters : [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

First, create the type, in SQL Server :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[myTvpType] AS TABLE 
(
    [RecordID] int,
    [TagID] int
)
```

And the C# code to insert your data :

```
internal void InsertData(SqlConnection connection, Dictionary<int, int> valuesToInsert)
{
    using (DataTable myTvpTable = CreateDataTable(valuesToInsert))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable SELECT RecordID, TagID FROM @myValues";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myValues", myTvpTable);
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

private DataTable CreateDataTable(Dictionary<int, int> valuesToInsert)
{
    // Initialize the DataTable
    DataTable myTvpTable = new DataTable();
    myTvpTable.Columns.Add("RecordID", typeof(int));
    myTvpTable.Columns.Add("TagID", typeof(int));

    // Populate DataTable with data
    foreach(key in valuesToInsert.Key)
    {
        DataRow row = myTvpTable.NewRow();
        row["RecordID"] = valuesToInsert[key];
        row["TagID"] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the tip, this solves the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to add the new row to the table at the end of your loop.  myTvpTable.Rows.Add(row);

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sending your data as an xml string and convert in into table in a stored procedure in sql. For example:
suppose I am sending multiple rows to add/update in an sql table then here are the steps:

1. Convert your class or list of class into an xml string using following method:

   ```
   public static string SerializeObjectToXmlString(object value)

             {
             var emptyNamepsaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { 
                                       XmlQualifiedName.Empty });

       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
       var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
       settings.Indent = true;
       settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

       using (var stream = new StringWriter())
       using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
       {
           serializer.Serialize(writer, value, emptyNamepsaces);
           return stream.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now while sending data to the database convert your class object into xml 
   string (Here I am using entity framework in my code, you can do this without using it as well):

   ```
   bool AddUpdateData(List<MyClass> data)
   {
       bool returnResult = false;
       string datatXml = Helper.SerializeObjectToXmlString(data);
       var sqlparam = new List<SqlParameter>()
                    {
      new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "dataXml", Value = datatXml}

                    };
       var result = this.myEntity.Repository<SQL_StoredProc_ComplexType>().ExecuteStoredProc("SQL_StoredProc", sqlparam);
       if (result != null && result.Count() > 0)
       {
           returnResult = result[0].Status == 1 ? true : false;
       }
       return returnResult;
   }
   ```
3. Now your SQL Code:

3.1 Declare a table variable:

```sql
DECLARE @tableVariableName TABLE
(
    ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20)
)
```

3.2 Insert Your xml string into Table variable

```sql
INSERT INTO @tableVariableName
SELECT 
    Finaldata.R.value ('(ID/text())[1]', 'INT') AS ID, 
    Finaldata.R.value ('(Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Name
FROM @MyInputXmlString.nodes ('//ArrayMyClass/MyClass') AS Finaldata (R)
```

3.3 Finally insert this table value into your sql table

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name)                  
SELECT ID, Name          
FROM @tableVariableName
```

This will save your effort of hitting database again and again using a for loop.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.