# Error Passing ARRAY for Stored Procedure Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

Iam trying to pass an array to a method then using it to a Stored procedure

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] names = new string[3] { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
    string User = "Employee";
    mav.AccessType(names,User);
}
```

METHOD:

```
   public void AccessType(String[] ARR, String Userty)
{
    SysCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdC = new SqlCommand("sp_AccessTypes", SysCon);
    cmdC.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ARRAY", ARR);
    cmdC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", Userty);
    cmdC.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SysCon.Close();
}
```

STORED PROC

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AccessType] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ARRAY AccessType1 Readonly,
@USER nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO tbl_samplednd1(UserType,parameter1) SELECT * FROM @ARRAY
END
```

it gives an error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed
>   provider native type.

How to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Can you tell us the parent type of AccessType1 on the SQL server?

Comment: You can't pass an array as a SQL Server's parameter, because it does not support arrays.

Comment: I use User-Defined Table Types. And that is **AccessType1**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS SQL Server does not support arrays to be given as SP parameters.
As you said in your comment, the `@ARRAY` parameter is not an array either, it is a user defined table type.

Thus you should prepare a `System.Data.DataTable` in your .net code and pass it as the parameter.

You can find a good example in this question:

[How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

Your `DataTable` should contain at least two rows that has the information to fill `UserType` and `parameter1` columns of the table `tbl_samplednd1`