# C++ Examples of how to pass 500 records to Sql Server Stored procedure using ADO

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado

I am writing a c++ program using ADO's command and would like to pass multiple records to a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure at the same time.  Is this possible?  How would I do this?

A record might have multiple values to it.  For example a record is worker (name, number, startDate)

Comment: I have seen this done by building an insert statement and passing that text to the SP.  One insert statement with many values.

Comment: I would prefer not to have to build a really long query.  I was hoping to pass the data and then have the stored procedure do all the work.

Comment: You can pass in a long string with delimiters.  I have seen posts that mention a table valued parameter.  The long query approach is simple and allows a 'bulk insert' rather than multiple single inserts (built by the SP) which has a big impact on performance.

Comment: Here is a post that describes the table parameter solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code

Comment: So that post is using ADO.net.  Where I am currently using classic ADO and C++.  Wouldn't passing in a long insert statement, possibly 500 records, take a while.

Comment: I don't think ADO can do this, at least not as efficiently as ODBC or OLE/DB (where you can submit multiple parameter sets in a single operation). And while it's possible to get ADO interfaces from OLE/DB I don't think the reverse is true. ADO was meant for pre .net visual basic and is thus fairly limited.

Comment: Passing in long strings is faster than individual inserts.  My preference would be to put business logic in the application and use SqlBulkInsert object.  Have not used C++ in 15 years, not sure if you can call .Net DLLS or if SqlBulkInsert is available outside .Net.  Another option would be to create a text file and use command line BulkInsert.