# Sql query with multiple ids in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have following method

```
public SomeObj LoadSomeData(int id)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        var result = 
            context.Database.SqlQuery<SomeObj>
            ($"SELECT * FROM SOMEOBJECT WHERE id = {id}")
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works fine, now the specification has changed, and I need to lookup multiple `ids`. I get ids as list of int and return a list. I read a bit about Sql Query and I can use `IN` and pass multiple values. So this is my changes:

```
public List<SomeObj> LoadSomeData(List<int> listOfIds)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        var result = 
            context.Database.SqlQuery<SomeObj>
            ($"SELECT * FROM SOMEOBJECT WHERE id IN ({id})") <-- I am not sure how to pass list in 
        return result;
    }
}
```

The second method works when I pass values manually to the query like 1,2,3 etc. but how can I pass list of to query?

Comment: What do you mean multiple id's, instead of returning a specific id you want to grab a batch of records with those id's?

Comment: `($"SELECT * FROM SOMEOBJECT WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved different ways. I would suggest one way to go is using `Join` method.

```
var ids = string.Join(",", listOfIds)
```

This would return a list of `{1, 2, 3}` to string of `1, 2, 3`

So putting that together with your final method would look like this:

```
public List<SomeObj> LoadSomeData(List<int> listOfIds)
{
    var ids = string.Join(",", listOfIds)
    using (var context = new KmdDataContext())
    {
        var result = 
            context.Database.SqlQuery<SomeObj>
            ($"SELECT * FROM SOMEOBJECT WHERE id IN ({Ids})")
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you this sovled the issue, i can not vote, but will accept this

Answer (score 4):

You can pass them by generating the list:

```
var idList = string.Join(",", listOfIds);
$"SELECT * FROM SOMEOBJECT WHERE id IN ({idList})")
```

But if the list gets big (from memory, more than 2000 or so) that will fail. If you need more than that, use a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine) - a bit more effort to set up, but they are very neat and scalable.

Answer (score 3):

Try `String.Join(",", listofids)` to convert the list into a comma separated string that you can use in the In part of the sql query

Comment: I guess i was a bit slow , the guys answered the same as i did . +1  for them

Comment: Since .Net 4 you don't have to create an array with `ToArray()` as you can pass an `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Ahmad listofids already a list why would you convert it to array? and join is with capital Join. but else you get my vote as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a collection, you could simply do.

```
var ids = String.Join(",", parameters.Where(value => value > 5 && value < 10));
```

Now you would be able to pass the variable to query.

```
var query = $"SELECT * FROM ... WHERE Id IN ({ids})";
```

Comment: .. where do the values 5 and 10 come from?

Comment: @stuartd Just used it as a basic where clause to filter the collection down to place the range.  Assuming the list has more than he would like to actually query against.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `LINQ` and `Entity Framework`.  From your example, there is no apparent need to use raw `SQL`.

```
public List<SomeObj> LoadSomeData(List<int> listOfIds)
{
    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
        return context.SomeObj.Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
    }
}
```

This is the equivalent to `WHERE id in (1,2,3)`