# SQL Server stored procedure not seeing parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, user-defined-types

I'm using C# to call a stored procedure and fill it from a datatable, but I'm doing something wrong.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getStationInfo]
    @stationList AS dbo.udtableStationCode READONLY
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM stations
    WHERE StationCode IN (SELECT * FROM @stationList) 
END
```

This procedure uses this user-defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udtableStationCode] 
     AS TABLE (StationCode NVARCHAR(50))
```

I'm trying to send a datatable to the stored procedure and get the result back in another datatable. Here's my C#:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getStationInfo", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dtStationsReturned = new DataTable())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.getStationInfo";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationList", dtStationCodes);
                    ada.Fill(dtStationsReturned);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

No matter what I try, when my code gets to the 'ada.Fill' line, I get the error:

> The procedure "getStationInfo" has no parameter named "@stationList".

But the stored procedure `getStationInfo` clearly DOES have that parameter. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

EDIT: I've checked the contents of `dtStationCodes`, and it's fine.

EDIT: Here is how I am creating my `dtStationCodes` datatable:

```
DataTable dtStationCodes = new DataTable();
dtStationCodes.Columns.Add("StationCode", typeof(String));
```

Comment: Do you get the the same error with `cmd.Parameters.Add("@stationList", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dtStationCodes;`? [AddWithValue is evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: @Dan Guzman, thanks, tried your suggestion, same error.

Comment: Do you have multiple databases? Have you perhaps updated one but not the other?

Comment: Aw CRAP! That was it! I have multiple connections, and my code was talking to a different test server. Everyone who was kind enough to respond, I am so sorry for wasting your time. I'm the stupidest person in the world.

Comment: @buckshot this happens to best of us, keep making mistakes and keep improving. go easy on yourself

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.getStationInfo", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            using (DataTable dtStationsReturned = new DataTable())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.getStationInfo";
                SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter("@stationList", dtStationCodes);
                sp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                sp.TypeName = "dbo.udtableStationCode";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(sp);
                ada.Fill(dtStationsReturned);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code) for another example of passing user defined table types.

Also see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#configuring-a-sqlparameter-example) for more information on creating SqlParameters and passing TVPs to a stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you @pcdev. I'm now getting "UdtTypeName property must be set only for UDT parameters." But your suggestion seems to be a UDT parameter. Similar error, same issue...?

Comment: that gives me my original error. You fixed whatever the other thing was, but the original problem remains.

Comment: Problem solved, see comments to OP. Wasting everybody's time, sorry.   : |

Comment: Hey, these things happen!  Glad you found the issue