# Stored procedure with table value parameter but ad-hoc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan, table-valued-parameters, adhoc-queries

I have a stored procedure like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryData] 
    @supplierId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @numbers dbo.ListNumbers READONLY,
    @locations dbo.ListLocations READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
        i.Field1,
        i.Field2,
        i.Field3,
        i.Field4
    FROM 
        dbo.Inventory AS i WITH (index(idx_Inventory_Abc_Xyz))
    JOIN 
        @numbers o ON i.OemNumber = o.OemNumber
    JOIN 
        @locations AS l ON l.YardLocation = i.YardLocation
    WHERE 
        i.SupplierId = @supplierId
        AND i.PartType <> 'ABC'
        AND i.PartType <> 'XYZ'
END
```

This is how I call the stored procedure:

```sql
DECLARE @p2 dbo.Locations  

INSERT INTO @p2 VALUES (N'AA1')  
INSERT INTO @p2 VALUES (N'AA3')    

DECLARE @p3 dbo.ListNumbers  

INSERT INTO @p3 VALUES (N'631006CA0A')    


EXEC GetInventoryData 
           @supplierId = 'e418fac4-c89e-4f5d-ad7d-ee7fcba7f41f',
           @locations = @p2,
           @numbers = @p3
```

The above stored procedure sometime got timeout while almost time it just took < 1s.

I check system and see that compilations/sec is high, and it suggested that ad-hoc queries can be reason.

Then I used this query to list ad-hoc query:

```sql
SELECT text, cp.objtype, cp.size_in_bytes
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan'
  AND cp.objtype IN (N'Adhoc', N'Prepared')
  AND cp.usecounts = 1
ORDER BY cp.size_in_bytes DESC 
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

!!! Here is sql plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkP5cAOW9

My question is why my stored procedure an ad-hoc query? I guess table value parameter cause it. Can someone explain, also give me some idea to fix issue please

**Update**: added .NET code to call stored procedure

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Why did you need to use index hint for `idx_Inventory_Abc_Xyz` index?

Comment: @D-Shid just want to make sure that it used correct index

Comment: Its pretty rare that you can pick a better index than SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK yeah maybe, but almost times the stored proceduce work good ( <1 sec) while sometime it took 7-10 seconds even more. So I guess the index hint is still fine

Comment: The thing about investigating performance issues is to simplify the factors as much as possible...

Comment: @minhhungit Did you want to as why it sometimes be slow or SP be `ad-hoc`? if you want to ask why sometimes be slow I might answer it, but another one I don't know

Comment: @D-Shid it's okay to understand more why it's sometime slow so please

Comment: For heavy use of differently sized Table Valued Parameters it might be worth switching on Trace Flag 2453, see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/using-trace-flag-2453-improve-table-variable-performance/. If you are calling the procedure from a client app then do not use the batch at the top (with the `DECLARE... INSERT`) instead use the client driver's tools to pass a Table Valued Parameter directly

Comment: thanks @Charlieface I will try the flag, btw, I call stored procedure from client and it auto generates ```DECLARE ... INSERT```

Comment: You will find that it doesn't actually generate that code, it is merely a represntation generated by the SQL Profiler of what the inserts might look like if they were T-SQL code. It's actually a high-performance `BULK INSERT` style codepath sent directly over the TDS protocol, and the recompilation count is actually a artifact that can be safely ignored. See also https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/tvps-and-plan-compilation-the-reprise/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56744520/14868997

Comment: Please share the query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Without seeing query plans I couldn't say for sure, but a performance boost could be had by making the two Table Types have primary keys. You can declare them inline like this `CREATE TYPE dbo.ListNumbers (Value int PRIMARY KEY);`

Comment: @Charlieface here is the plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkP5cAOW9

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, I did created user defined type as you can see in parameter zone of above stored procedure

Comment: Looks like `DISTINCT` is your main issue here, as it is causing a `Sort`. Why is it necessary? If the two table types have primary keys then they should not be causing duplicates. I suggest you remove it. Which client driver are you using? ADO.Net should be making ad-hoc queries just because of table types, but other drivers may be different

Comment: @Charlieface I'm using ADO.NET

Comment: @Charlieface I updated this post and add image for the code, please check

Comment: Please don't add images of code, just paste them in as text. Yeah that looks mostly OK, except for that you should specify the table type name `AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.ListLocation")`, and if there are any parameters that are `varchar` or `nvarchar` then you should use `DbString` and set `IsAnsi` and `Length` explicitly

Comment: @Charlieface yep, I have table name, it's inside PriorityLocationCollection class, it's also define column type, something like:

```
var sqlRow = new SqlDataRecord(
                new SqlMetaData("YardLocation", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50),
                new SqlMetaData("Priority", SqlDbType.Int));
```

Comment: You should specify it directly on the table parameter as I mentioned `locationData.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.ListLocation")`

Answer (score 1):

> The above stored procedure sometime got timeout while almost time it just took <1s.

Because you might encounter *parameter sniffing*,

values passed into the parameter are evaluated and used to create an execution plan for stored procedure that stored execution plan in the plan cache.

> because compiling queries is expensive, SQL Server will re-use them as much as possible.

That will cause the execution plan might not be the best for every query parameters.

There are some ways you can avoid *parameter sniffing*

1. Add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` in the queries or procedure

that way will tell sql-server don't try to keep the execution plan, so you will get a suitable plan from QO every execution time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryData] 
    @supplierId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @numbers dbo.ListNumbers READONLY,
    @locations dbo.ListLocations READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
        i.Field1,
        i.Field2,
        i.Field3,
        i.Field4
    FROM dbo.Inventory AS i with(index(idx_Inventory_Abc_Xyz))
    JOIN @numbers o ON i.OemNumber = o.OemNumber
    JOIN @locations AS l ON l.YardLocation = i.YardLocation
    WHERE i.SupplierId = @supplierId
    AND i.PartType <> 'ABC'
    AND i.PartType <> 'XYZ'
    OPTION(RECOMPILE)
END
```

But this way might cause your CPU high, if you execute stored procedure many times in short time

2. Add `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` or DECLARE local var to carry parameter.

`OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` That will create a plan that it expects to work well for all values of all parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryData] 
    @supplierId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @numbers dbo.ListNumbers READONLY,
    @locations dbo.ListLocations READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
        i.Field1,
        i.Field2,
        i.Field3,
        i.Field4
    FROM dbo.Inventory AS i with(index(idx_Inventory_Abc_Xyz))
    JOIN @numbers o ON i.OemNumber = o.OemNumber
    JOIN @locations AS l ON l.YardLocation = i.YardLocation
    WHERE i.SupplierId = @supplierId
    AND i.PartType <> 'ABC'
    AND i.PartType <> 'XYZ'
    OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
END
```

[parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I actually tried OPTION(RECOMPILE) long time ago, I also split stored proc to small stored proceduces to avoid parameter sniffing. My stored proc is called many many times all of day.
Base on posts: 
https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/compilations/ and https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/tvps-and-plan-compilation-the-reprise/ .....   I think it's mechanism of sql server. I'm trying to turn on "optimize for ad hoc workloads" btw.

Comment: one more note, I also tried to using brentozar scripts https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit but don't see it warning "parameter sniffing"

Comment: If your SQL server support QueyStore I would recommend you use that to analytics. execute plan from your SP https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If not you can try to use who is active to collect what's different between slow query and normal query plan, we can discuss it by those information http://whoisactive.com/