# Insert a lot of data from an Array into a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to create 900.000 new rows in a database and in each of these rows the entry from the array should be written into the column `Products`.

My solution mentioned below works but it takes over an hour. How can this be done faster?

My very slow solution:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 900000; i++) 
{
    string SQL_command = "INSERT INTO Database(Produkte) VALUES(" + ProductArray[i] + ")";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL_command , con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();              

    con.Close();
}
```

I use SQL Server and C#

Comment: Look into [Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code ... it talks about stored procedures but you can use `CommandType.Text` as well.

Comment: Besides TVPs, another method is [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). If you must do singleton inserts, use a parameterized statement and batch all in a single transaction.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: You can use a loop to build an sql string with a thousand parameter placeholders in, `INSERT x VALUES (@p0), (@p1), ... (@p999)`, and put a thousand parameters in the command, then run a loop that sets a thousand parameter values at a time and call execute 900 times instead of 900000 and times. Once you have the code done, see if doing 5000, 10000 at a time helps.. not sure I'd go for Dan's "do all 900000 in one hit" but he's a very smart guy so it could work out well!

Answer (score -3):

Instead of opening and closing your connection with each call, open the connection once, then run all the INSERT statements, then close the connection:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    con.Open();
    for (i = 1; i <= 900000; i++) {
        string SQL_command = "INSERT INTO Database(Produkte) VALUES(" + ProductArray[i] + ")";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL_command , con))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But with connection pooling, the connection will not be closed (though it will be reset). Perhaps some slight benefit but the agony here is inserting 1 row at a time.