# mssql UPDATE command does not always update node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, ssms

I am creating a node.js server using express. I am using mssql and sqlstring to query my SQL server. For one of my functions, I want to update some data within my 'records' column, however in certain cases, it only updates half of the information and in others, it works perfectly. Here is my current setup:

I created a temporary table `#current_samples` and have added the columns:

```
record_id int,
is_positive bit, 
time_of_test datetime2(7)
```

I am trying to create a temporary table with the new information, then update the records table with the temporary table.

Here is my SQL command I use after creating my temporary table:

```
UPDATE records SET records.time_of_test = c.time_of_test, records.is_positive = c.is_positive FROM records INNER JOIN #current_samples c ON (records.record_id = c.record_id)
```

I have checked to make sure my temporary table is correctly adding the columns, and it is. My issue is `UPDATE` sometimes works perfectly, and other times only updates HALF of the information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one but you can determine what, if anything, is going wrong. As a debugging aid, you can use the OUTPUT clause to log / review the rows that were updated. A slightly less precise check is to retrieve the value of @@rowcount immediately after that statement. If the table has an update trigger, you might want to review the logic. And this _temporary table is correctly adding the columns_ doesn't make sense. You generally don't "add columns" to a table after creation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code) Use a TVP instead of a temp table

Comment: I will try that. Thank you

Comment: I assume you are aware that a temp table only exists for the duration of the command? So if you try and create a temp table in one command and access it another it won't be there.

Comment: I tried what @Charlieface suggested (using MERGE) and after a few alterations, I got it to work. Also Dale K my temporary tables did not delete until disconnect so that was not the issue. I am still not sure why UPDATE only worked sometimes, and other times only HALF of the information was updated, but MERGE does work so thank you all!

Comment: By the sound of it, half the rows didn't actually exist? Are you trying to do an "upsert" (insert/update), then you need `MERGE`

Comment: The columns already existed within my table. I just wanted to update time_of_test and is_positive with new values, however sometimes it worked and other times only half of the values updated. If I ran the command twice, the half that didn't update were fixed. I solved the issue with a `MERGE`, however I am still confused why my UPDATE did not work.