Alternative to BULK INSERT on shared DB server
I have data update files with 50-100k records that need to be loaded to the database on a regular basis. I have a stored procedure that uses BULK INSERT to process the file in a couple of seconds max.
But BULK INSERT requires:
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS

which is a server level permission. My production SQL Server database exists on a shared cloud DB server. On the shared server, I am not allowed to have this permission.
My current solution opens the file and reads each line and inserts it into the table for later processing. Iterating through the file line by line is really slow. I'm looking for a performant alternative to BULK INSERT that only requires permissions at a database level.
Any ideas?

You can try bcp.exe command line SQL Server utility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

There are some c# and Java bulk classes which can be used instead, they don't require files and can work on stream of data. Google sqlserverbulkcopy and friends

If the server is located in the cloud don't forget that the server, in the cloud, would also need access to where ever that file is stored as well (you can't do BULK INSERT ... FROM <Some Local Path to the User>). If you aren't allowed to have BULK INSERT access, I suspect you also don't have access to upload the file to a BLOB location in the cloud that the SQL Server also has access to anyway (as you have no need to)?

Doing ordinary INSERTs in batches of a few hundred rows, with each batch surrounded by BEGIN / COMMIT, will speed things up a lot.

Depending on the size, I'd suggest that the server could probably deal with 100k rows in a single transaction easily too, @O.Jones .

I can't use bcp.exe because I don't have command line access on the server.
I have access to the file path (it gets FTP'ed to the application space.

You don't need command line access on the server, @Michael . You can launch the command line from your host and use bcp against the remote host.

I'm experimenting with batches but the reading of the file line by line also takes a lot longer than I would have thought.

@ThomA I can't launch bcp from my host because the updates are driven by users of the website. The action needs to be tied to an action on the website.

Im starting to feel like there's a lot of limitations you're not making us aware of. Perhaps you should talk to your service provider about the issue? Explain the problem you're having and finding out what solutions they offer (for you).

@siggemannen All bulk operations will be blocked, including SqlBulkCopy, bcp.exe and friends.

Best option might be a Table Valued Parameter (which uses bulk insert under the hood) then a INSERT...SELECT ... FROM @tvp

This bulk is code based, no files. It works, unless you have no sql rights at all

@siggemannen - I am trying your idea using SqlBulkCopy to batch thousands of updates into chunks for the DB. It is still a lot slower than using BULK INSERT but definitely faster than INSERTs. I am using ReadLines() to cache the file read and loading a DataTable with thousands of rows before committing with WriteToServer(). I'm experimenting with the number of rows to process at a time to optimize between memory footprint and speed.

@Michael, yeah the "real" bulk is very fast, and hard to beat. I've had some luck implementing multi-threaded bulk imports but it leads to complicated code. There are some options as well, especially tablock can sometimes speed things up. Good luck!

@Charlieface - I'm not sure what issue you are raising about blocking. Can you clarify? Also, how does Table Valued Parameter use a file? I thought the data already needed to be in a DB table?

If ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS is not given to the user then all bulk operations will fail, inluding bcp and SqlBulkCopy as they all use the same mechanism. Table Valued Parameters will be allowed though, as you only need EXECUTE permission on the table type. You can load the table valued parameter using SqlDataRecord see eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779567/14868997 which means it will stream through without buffering. Then the SQL statement is simply INSERT YourTable (ColumnsHere) SELECT ColumnsHere FROM @tvp The TVP acts like a table variable (like a temporary table).

While there may be additional options, I am finding that @siggemannen plan works for my situation. If you'd like credit for the answer, please post as an answer
